# PHP's exec() Function and the .history File

Tags: php, linux

Given that the user that apache is running as on my server is a real user and has a home directory with a .history file, will running commands via `exec()` cause entries to be made in that file?

For example if I run `exec("whoami")` and I login as that user and run the command `history` will I see an entry in that history for the `whoami` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

```
michael@MacMichi:~ $ php -r 'exec("whoami");'
michael@MacMichi:~ $ history |tail -n3
  506  history |tail -n3
  507  php -r 'exec("whoami");'
  508  history |tail -n3
```

And for the apache case: i tried it out, two years ago (2012), and saw that it didn't have any impact on the history. Just try it out if you are not sure...

---

Just a sidenote... the command is indeed interpreted by the shell, as you can see with this simple example

```
$ php -r 'exec("echo foo $(bar2 jojo) go >/dev/tty");'
sh: bar2: command not found
foo go
```

that's exactly the same output, as when I do this on the command line directly

```
$ echo foo $(bar2 jojo) go >/dev/tty
-bash: bar2: command not found
foo go
```

The important point here is, that the shell only adds commands to the history if it is in "interactive mode". When you do something like `cat|bash` or `bash -c $exec_command`, no history entry is created. That's what `exec()` does, btw. It is a call like the C command `execl("/bin/sh", "-c", exec_command, NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

the history file is also called "bash history" and is only related to calls, that are made inside the bash, the webserver itself is running in its own environment, every system call this process (its nothing more than that) does, has nothing todo with the bash ;)

Comment: @Michael  it has "nothing" todo with the bash, because the question is about "apache" and "php".

Comment: the built-in PHP function `exec()` calls the bash shell, which I proved in my answer